# loop logic, encrypting array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, encryption, for-loop, uppercase

I am trying to perform some operations on an array which the final goal is to do a simple encryption. But anyways my array is 458 characters long which consists of mostly letters and some commas, periods, etc. I am trying to start from last character of array and go to the first character and uppercase all the letters in the array. It reads the last character "" correctly, but then the next step in the for loop is like 4 characters over and skipped a few letters. Is something wrong with my control logic?

```
void EncryptMessage (ofstream& outFile, char charArray[], int length)
{
    int index;
    char upperCased;
    char current;

    for (index = length-1; index <= length; --index)
    {
        if (charArray[index] >= 'A' && charArray[index] <= 'Z')
        {
            upperCased = static_cast<char>(charArray[index]);
            current = upperCased;
            outFile << current;
        }
        else
        {
            charArray[index]++;
            current = charArray[index];
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
for (index = length-1; index <= length; --index)
```

to:

```
for (index = length-1; index >= 0; --index)
```

Comment: this works but i get really strange output that is in random order and none of the letters are upper cased

Comment: never mind the problem was in the else statement where there was a needless increment of the index again. works perfectly now

Comment: Are you wanting to change lowercase letters to uppercase letters only?

Comment: no the encryption includes subtracting asccii values as well, but removing a line from the else statement and fixing loop fixed it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the `else` leg of your `if` statement, you're setting the value of `current`, but never writing it out, so all that gets written out are what start as capital letters (and, as others have pointed out, your loop condition isn't correct).

If I were doing this, I'd structure it a bit differently. I'd write a small functor to encrypt a single letter:

```
struct encrypt { 
    char operator()(char input) { 
        if (isupper(input))
            return input;
        else
            return input+1;
    }
};
```

Then I'd put the input into an `std::string`, and operate on it using `std::transform`:

```
std::string msg("content of string goes here.");

std::transform(msg.rbegin(), msg.rend(), 
               std::ostream_iterator<char>(outFile, ""), 
               encrypt());
```